# Returning BigDecimal from CXF-Web Service

Tags: .net, web-services, cxf, bigdecimal

I have been using **Xfire** with aegis binding for a while and now I am migrating to CXF with aegis and am using a .Net client. The problem is that for all those methods which are returning **BigDecimal** values, the corresponding method generated on the .Net side returns void and instead has two extra parameters: out decimal return, out bool returnSpecified. Is there any way to change the return type back to **decimal?**. FYI all the other reference types are correctly represented.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using aegis configuration and forced the minOccurs attribute of the return value in wsdl to '1' (which by default is set to '0' in aegis).